# Dimensions of an Android Image

Tags: java, android, eclipse, photoshop, gimp

I am creating a reference app which has a navigation bar at the top and the information, in the form of an ImageView, below it surrounded by a ScrollView. I have worked out how to change the image when the next button is pressed. I noticed this being implemented on the below app. I am able to get all the programming working, but I am not to keen on visual editing.

http://media1.android-apps.com/images/pname/com.ninjacoders.mcanary/image1.png

What should the dimensions of the Image be in Gimp?

How would I go about creating customs home screen buttons, and what dimensions should I use for them?

Any further advice on how I should do this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From within GIMP, you should zoom enough your image - and work with the "pencil" tool, and the "pixel" brush (the one brush right after the pepper brush - they are sorted alphabetically) - this will allow you to proper edit pixel-art images.

You can use teh colorpicker and create a new palette resort to let it easier to pick the few grey tones you are using.

To get to know the exact dimensions, one of the tools in GIMP's toolbox is the "measure" tool - use it to get to know which icon size you need.

As a final tip: do your work on this larger image, and draw the icons you want in separate layers - whenever an icon is done, crop its layer using the crop tool, with the option "crop layers" on (else it will crop the whole image) - and then drage the thumbnail for  the image layer containing your icon from the layers dialog into the toolbox - this will create a new image consisting of the icon alone (and is a quite faster workflow than copy + paste as new image).